# Set file to State ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

In my react component I have :

```
 state = {
        title: '',
        content: '',
        file: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log(this.state)
    }



 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

 <input type="text" id="title" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

 <textarea id="content" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>

 <input type="file" id="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

</form>
```

and i am getting in `console.log(this.state)` only path to `file`, like : `"C:\fakepath\title.jpg"`.
How to set to state actual file?
Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: do you mean display the selected file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for read file from event you must be use `e.target.files[0]`
bellow code works fine for you

```js
state = {
      title: '',
      content: '',
      file: ''
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleOnFileChange = (e) => {
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : file
        })
    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log(this.state)
    }



    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

       <input type="text" id="title" onChange={this.handleOnFileChange}/>

       <textarea id="content" onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>

       <input type="file" id="file" onChange={this.handleChange}/>

    </form>
```

Comment: Now how can I reassign this stored file to the input file tag, because when I changed the state the file automatically deselect?

Comment: it will not, we are not controlling the file input by state